# 14393.67 Installation Failure on my 520

Tags: redstone-builds, unsupported-phones

Redstone updates are not supported on 512mb RAM devices, but i somehow managed to get the updates using **DHTUpgrade Advisor**, and i got 14393.67.

Now after downloading updates, it started installing. The process goes till 100% and then i get an error saying, please try again, i forgot the error code, but the message said, please try again.

I already did this 4-5 times, and am getting the same error. Please help me!

Comment: It might help if you posted the actual error code.

Comment: There's also a reason why the builds are unsupported :)